# Android Java: How to convert Google AppEngine EP response to Custom Object usnig AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, endpoint

My Google API Endpoint returns a JSON Map. I'm struggeling with converting the underlining ArrayMaps of my custom Objects to original type. My custom objects extend GenericJSON by default because they were generated by Eclipse. I can't imagine that is have to write a converter myself .

My goal is to stay in line with google standards as long as i can.

Endpoint Consuming:

```
JsonMap epResult = ep.checkForYousAccounts(phoneContacts, regId).execute();
```

Generated Endpoint Model JSONMap:

```
import com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson;

public final class JsonMap extends GenericJson {
    public JsonMap() {
    }

    public JsonMap set(String fieldName, Object value) {
        return (JsonMap)super.set(fieldName, value);
    }

    public JsonMap clone() {
        return (JsonMap)super.clone();
    }
}
```

Generated Endpoint Model class:

```
public final class User extends GenericJson {
    @Key("abo_status")
    private String aboStatus;
    @Key
    private String activationCode;
    @Key
    private DateTime birthday;
    @Key
    @JsonString
    private Long countRating;
    @Key
    private String defaultLocale;
    @Key
    private String defaultTimezone;
    @Key
    private String email;
    @Key
    @JsonString
    private List<Long> friends;
    @Key
    @JsonString
    private Long id;
...
```

Comment: Do you have code to show us ?

Comment: anyone was able to get this done?